# Is it acceptable to write "play games"?

Tags: infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

All you can do is play games.
Is it acceptable to write " play games" instead of "to play games"?

Comment: "Play games" sounds better to me than "to play games." I'm sure it's OK but I don't have any research for a more solid answer.

Comment: Can you expand more on the context in which you want to use this phrase?  Both "play games" and "to play games" have their place; it depends on the particular sentence you're writing.  If the use is solely in the first sentence of your question, then I agree that the correct form is "play games."

Answer (score 1):

You can use either to-infinitive (to play) or bare-infinitive (play) in the sentence presented. I think you find the former more in writing or formal speech and the latter more in conversation or informal writing.

Comment: Thanks, Khan.I'd like to know whether there is any grammar rule to write like this.

Comment: I have found both in dictionaries. For examples: All we ever want is go shopping (Collins).  All that we want is to sleep (The Free Dictionary).